# Modify make_heap in C++ algorithm STL to work as a minimum heap

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I am sure I am making some really silly mistake but haven't been able to point it out. The `make_heap` function in the `algorithm` STL of C++ has the syntax

`void make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(),Compare comp );`
where v is declared as an `int` vector.
Now the comp input defaults to `<` but I want to change it so that I can use it to make both min and max heaps. Looking at other examples what makes sense to me is doing something like,

`void make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(),std::less<int> );`

OR

`void make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(),std::greater<int> );`

but I keep on getting the compiler error `expected primary expression before ')' token`

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong?
Any help?

Comment: You're passing a type for the third parameter. It needs to be an *object instance* of a type fulfilling the comparator requirements. Put some `()` on the end of that thing. And the `void` make no sense at all.

Comment: You are missing a pair of parentheses after  `std::less<int>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `()` at the end

```
void make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<int>());
```

### Reason

`priority_queue` signature -

```
template <class T, class Container = vector<T>,
class Compare = less<typename Container::value_type> > class priority_queue;
```

So, it takes a `Compare` class (not `Compare` class object) as third argument. So `priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>()> Q;` will yield compilation error because you need to pass a `Compare` class (a binary predicate). Correct syntax is -

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> Q;
```

`make_heap` signature is -

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
void make_heap (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last,
                Compare comp );
```

which take `Compare` class object. So `make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<int>());` will give compilation error. You need to a `Compare` class object (a binary function) here.

Hope it helps!